# Possible to declare static object in urdf file?

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, urdf, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a bunch of objects as urdf files which I use for simulation in Gazebo and visualization in Rviz. Now I would like some of them to be fixed in the environment. As stated [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11719/fixed-urdf-object-in-gazebo) this is possible with Gazebo xml model files by putting following tag in the model.

```
<static>true</static>
```

However, simply putting the same tag in the gazebo extension of the urdf file like so:

```
<gazebo reference="my_object">
  <static>true</static>
</gazebo>
```

does not work, it simply gets ignored. I would like to use urdf files instead of Gazebo model xml's since urdf's can be easily visualized in Rviz by reading the description from the parameter server which does not seem to work for Gazebo model xml's. So, the question is whether there is a way to literally fix objects in their urdf file description opposed to simply making them very heavy.

Thanks,
-Robert-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29437/possible-to-declare-static-object-in-urdf-file?/) by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2012-03-09

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just add extension without the reference attribute to your model:

```
<gazebo>
    <static>true</static>
</gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on 2012-03-12**:
Perfect, thank you!

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-04-16**:
Is it possible to make only a specific link static?  I want only the base_link of my robot arm to be static (i.e. welded in place) while other links and joints can be actuated.

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-12**:
@Rufus, did you ever find a solution to this question? I am having the same issue.

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-05-15**:
@matthewmarkey My conclusion was that I don't believe it is possible.  The only way to achieve something similar is to explicitly specify in the `urdf` file a fixed joint between the world and the `base_link`

```
 <link name="world" />

 <joint name="world_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world" />
    <child link = "base_link" />
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.1" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
 </joint>
```

I think it's unfortunate that changing where to spawn the arm (base link) requires changing the `urdf`.  I would hope this can be done similar to spawning static objects in gazebo, just changing some parameters in the launch file.

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-18**:
Ok thank you @Rufus. When you change this in the URDF, should you also run the MSA again now that you have changed the URDF?

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-05-19**:
@matthewmarkey what is MSA??

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-20**:
The Moveit Setup Assistant.

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-05-20**:
I've never used Moveit Setup Assistant before so I'm not sure

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-20**:
Ok, thank you. I am unsure of what I am doing wrong, but I am using your method above with no success. Is it possible for you to check out my URDF and SRDF? I would really appreciate it...[URDF](https://github.com/matthewmarkey44/arm/blob/master/src/version1_desc/urdf/arm2.urdf) and [SRDF](https://github.com/matthewmarkey44/arm/blob/master/src/t800/config/arm.srdf).

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-05-21**:
I can't tell by the looks of it what's wrong (I'm also no expert in urdf and srdf).  If you could describe what's wrong, that would be useful.  Is the whole arm frozen (i.e. joints cannot be actuated)?  Is the whole arm not fixed (i.e. the whole arm including the base flails around)?

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-05-21**:
Also you might want to edit the .xacro file instead of the .urdf file if the .xacro file is used to generate and overwrite the .urdf file

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-21**:
I am using the URDF for generation.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3ppf2po_uU) is the output if I am using the "world" link tag as shown in the above URDF.

I have been getting some advice from someone on reddit and they suggested that the joint_states could be receiving states from multiple sources but I am unsure of how to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Robert,

you can fix a model to the world by adding the following lines to your URDF file:

```
<link name="world" />
<joint name="world_joint"  type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="2 0 1.5" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="your_models_root_link"/>
</joint>
```

Note that the object is fixed to the world at the position you specify in the joint, not the parameters you give to spawn_model.

---

Originally posted by [Kai Bublitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1332/kai-bublitz/) with karma: 357 on 2012-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on 2012-03-09**:
Thanks, that works but I'm still wondering if it's possible to set Gazebo`s static tag so that the physics engine doesn't try to recompute the fixed object's state at every iteration.

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2018-08-29**:
Hm for me it does not work... If I start the simulation my object (here: your_models_root_link) just falls down..... even with:

```
<gazebo reference="your_models_root_link">
    <static>true</static>
</gazebo>
```